# Cannot access nas from wired network but with wifi yes

Tags: networking, network-shares, smb2

I please need help to understand one problem that is driving me crazy.
I have at home a lan network and recently i had to change router, so i put one that i already had: an Archer D7 from tp-linlk with the last firmware.
When i changed router, i had to change also position to it, so i arranged cables to make little order in that room.

I have a buffalo linkstation connected with cable to router. I has smb 2.0 enabled.
I have an old HP desktp PC with windows 10 freshly installed (it had Windows 7 but when i updated it hoping to solve this problem) and my laptop with windows 10 too. The dekstop pc is connected with cable.

From both pc if i type \nas\ (or the ip 192.168.2.6), i type username and password and then:

- using Wifi (integrated on my laptop, with an usb dongle on pc desktop) i can see folders and i can browse them
- using wired connection, after insert my credentials (correct) i can see only 1st level of shared folders, but i can't browse them.
  it stays there long time without any error but "working" cursors. If i switch to wifi, it enters inside folders.

Here everything i tried:

- change cable
- change port on router
- update pc desktop to windows 10
- change the rj connectors to nas and dekstop cables
- leave connected only the nas and 1 pc
- tried with my laptop (as i noticed the problem on my desktop pc, so i tried with my laptop)
- disable wifi guest network on router
- disable smb 1 on pc
- disable ipv6 on pc
- uninstall and reinstall network adapter on
- disable windows firewall and defender (i still have not installed any antivirus)
- change dns server to 192.168.2.1 and 8.8.8.8
- access with ip instead of nas' name
- allow everything in advanced sharing center for all profiles
- sharing a folder from my laptop it is accessible from the desktop one (it works)
- on nas share a folder browsable by anyone (i can't go inside it)
- tried to use Wireshark but i don't know what to search

I finished ideas about what problem can be and what to do.

If you please have any suggestion i will appreciate it.

Thank you very much
Have a nice day

Comment: Since you can connect by Wi-Fi but not by Wired, try a TCP/IP Reset:   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer and test.

Comment: Thank you @John for your answer. unluckily it still doesn't work. Running this command as administrator, on both pc, between the output lines of the command, i get only one "access denied"

Comment: I noticed that if i unplug the cable that connects the Antenna to the router (into WAN port), everything works fine. Now i must understand what to do

Comment: Is there some sort of extra connection that is causing the issue?

Comment: Pardon, i don't understand. I have only WAN Connection through small dish of my operator. No backup sim or others things

Comment: That clarifies.  You need to ask your ISP to give you an Ethernet port from your dish. They should be able to do this. Then put a router on that and hook up normally. Your ISP can help you here.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to connect the old router and it works, so maybe i configured something bad in the tp-link. I opened ticket on their support.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with a similar issue on a win11 home Asus laptop. On the two other computers on the network, all my NAS show up in Ethernet, on this it does not. It also will not appear on wifi unless I type in the NAS name, on Ethernet it returns an error typing the NAS name.
On both wifi and Ethernet, I can ping the address and it returns with no errors.
I attempted the reset and after rebooting, the Ethernet no longer finds ANY of the NAS's on the network. Wifi still works, but I still have to access the NAS by entering the address into the address bar, it does not display in the 'network' list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150511)

Comment: Hello @LEH, unluckily i couldn't find a solution even on tp link community. Here the discussion. https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/223570

Comment: You should try to edit the hosts file and map name to ip. The reason why one pc doens't need this and others no, it's unclear to me